# Eliminate blank/nullable cells in a matrix in SSRS

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I want to suppress null values in a column group.

My dataset looks like below:

```
ProductId   CategoryId  Amount
10000024    1           0
10000025    1           0
10000026    2           10000
10000027    2           110
10000028    1           11110
```

﻿RowGrouping -> ProductId

ColumnGrouping -> CategoryId

I have to repeat the ProductId and Amount based on the the CategoryId. So, ProductId column is placed inside columngrouping.

But as shown below, Rows are not displaying properly

Actual Result:

```
ProductId      Amount   ProductId   Amount
10000024       0
10000025       0
                        10000026    10000
                        10000027    110
10000028       11110
```

Expected Result:

```
ProductId      Amount   ProductId   Amount
10000024       0        10000026    10000
10000025       0        10000027    110
10000028       11110
```

Note: CategoryId is not displayed in the report.It is only used in grouping.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: It has to do with the column grouping. The only way I could think to get your expected results would be to use a nested tablix within the matrix.

Comment: @aduguid Yeah, you are correct. Even I tried adding tablix with ProductId grouping to matrix and removed the Rowgrouping from Matrix, it worked. Anyway, Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help